Your submission contained sn-bibliography.bib and no associated sn-bibliography.tex file
I am trying to submit my latex source folder on arxive, but I get this error:
Your submission contained sn-bibliography.bib and no associated sn-bibliography.tex file.
I have generated this folder from overleaf (submit -> submit to arxive -> download files - > download project zip with submission files). Here is the picture of what I have in my folder:

I appreciate your help on this. Also, I have tried other solutions but they did not work. Here is what I have tried so far:
enter link description here
enter link description here

Delete all .bst and .bib files. Just include your .bbl file with you .tex, and .cls (and the figures and .eps of course.

@Mane32 Thank you, your solution helped, but now I get a new error for which I did not find any solution by seraching. error:
"*** File .DS_Store has been removed ***
Removed hidden file .DS_Store"

Delete the .DS_Store file hidden in your folder. In Mac is Command + Shift + . 

@Mane32 it worked! thanks!
